# Is it possible to route a single request to all instances with ELB?

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb

I have a post request that will do a trigger to server code to cache data in the memory for all instances. So I need to route this request to all instances though nginx. Is it possible to configure it in ELB?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible with ELB. I suggest either using a management tool like Chef or using the AWS API to query the address of all instances in the ELB and make a request to each one